# Zend Framework: image upload

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I want to upload an image with Zend Framework version 1.9.6. The uploading itself works fine, but I want a couple of other things as well ... and I'm completely stuck.

- Error messages for failing to upload an image won't show up.
- If a user doesn't enter all the required fields but has uploaded an image then I want to display the uploaded image in my form. Either as an image or as a link to the image. Just some form of feedback to the user.
- I want to use Zend_ Validate_ File_ IsImage. But it doesn't seem to do anything.
- And lastly; is there some automatic renaming functionality?

All ideas and suggestions are very welcome. I've been struggling for two days now.

These are simplified code snippets:

**myform.ini**

```
method = "post"

elements.title.type = "text"
elements.title.options.label = "Title"
elements.title.options.attribs.size = 40
elements.title.options.required = true

elements.image.type = "file"
elements.image.options.label = "Image"
elements.image.options.validators.isimage.validator = "IsImage"

elements.submit.type = "submit"
elements.submit.options.label = "Save"
```

**TestController**

```
<?php
class Admin_TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  public function testAction ()
  {
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(MY_SECRET_PATH . 'myform.ini');
    $f = new Zend_Form($config);

    if ($this->_request->isPost())
    {
      $data = $this->_request->getPost();

      $imageElement = $f->getElement('image');
      $imageElement->receive();

      //$imageElement->getValue();

      if ($f->isValid($data))
      {
        //save data
        $this->_redirect('/admin');
      }

      else
      {
        $f->populate($data);
      }
    }

    $this->view->form = $f;
  }
}
?>
```

My view just echo's the 'form' variable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, put this at the start of your script:

error_reporting(E_ALL);//this should show all php errors

I think the error messages are missing from the form because you re-populate the form before you display it. I think that wipes out any error messages. To fix that, remove this part:

```
else
{
   $f->populate($data);
}
```

To show the uploaded image in the form, just add a div to your view template, like this:

```
<div style="float:right"><?=$this->image?></div>
```

If the image uploaded ok, then populate $view->image with an img tag.

As for automatic re-naming, no, it's not built in, but it's very easy. I'll show you how below.
Here's how I handle my image uploads:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);

$image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');
$image->setLabel('Upload an image:')
      ->setDestination($config->paths->upload)
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->setMaxFileSize(10240000) // limits the filesize on the client side
      ->setDescription('Click Browse and click on the image file you would like to upload');
$image->addValidator('Count', false, 1);                // ensure only 1 file
$image->addValidator('Size', false, 10240000);            // limit to 10 meg
$image->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');// only JPEG, PNG, and GIFs

$form->addElement($image);

$this->view->form = $form;

if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{
    if(!$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
    {
        return $this->render('add');
    }

    if(!$form->image->receive())
    {
        $this->view->message = '<div class="popup-warning">Errors Receiving File.</div>';
        return $this->render('add');
    }

    if($form->image->isUploaded())
    {
        $values = $form->getValues();
        $source = $form->image->getFileName();

        //to re-name the image, all you need to do is save it with a new name, instead of the name they uploaded it with. Normally, I use the primary key of the database row where I'm storing the name of the image. For example, if it's an image of Person 1, I call it 1.jpg. The important thing is that you make sure the image name will be unique in whatever directory you save it to.

        $new_image_name = 'someNameYouInvent';

        //save image to database and filesystem here
        $image_saved = move_uploaded_file($source, '/www/yoursite/images/'.$new_image_name);
        if($image_saved)
        {
            $this->view->image = '<img src="/images/'.$new_image_name.'" />';
            $form->reset();//only do this if it saved ok and you want to re-display the fresh empty form
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, have a look at the [Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) tutorial. Note how it has an ErrorController.php that will display error messages for you. Also note how the application.ini has these lines to cause PHP to emit error messages, but make sure you're in the "development" environment to see them (which is set in public/.htaccess).

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Second, ZF has a renaming filter for file uploads:

```
$upload_elt = new Zend_Form_Element_File('upload');
$upload_elt
->setRequired(true)
->setLabel('Select the file to upload:')
->setDestination($uploadDir)
->addValidator('Count', false, 1) // ensure only 1 file
->addValidator('Size', false, 2097152) // limit to 2MB
->addValidator('Extension', false, 'doc,txt')
->addValidator('MimeType', false, 
               array('application/msword',
                 'text/plain'))
->addFilter('Rename', implode('_', 
                  array($this->_user_id,
                    $this->_upload_category,
                    date('YmdHis'))))
->addValidator('NotExists', false, $uploadDir)
;
```

Some of the interesting things above:

- mark the upload as required (which your .ini doesn't seem to do)
- put all the uploads in a special directory
- limit file size and acceptable mime types
- rename upload to myuser_category_timestamp
- don't overwrite an existing file (unlikely, given our timestamp scheme, but let's make sure anyway)

So, the above goes in your form. In the controller/action that receives the upload, you could do this:

```
$original_filename = $form->upload->getFileName(null, false);
if ($form->upload->receive()) {
  $model->saveUpload(
    $this->_identity, $form->upload->getFileName(null, false),
    $original_filename
  );
}
```

Note how we capture the $original_filename (if you need it) before doing receive(). After we receive(), we do getFileName() to get the thing that the rename filter picked as the new filename.

Finally, in the model->saveUpload method you could store whatever stuff to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view also outputs any error messages that you generate in the controller: loading errors, field validation, file validation. Renaming would be your job, as would other post processing such as by image-magick convert.

Answer (score 0):

When following lo_fye's listing I experienced problems with custom decorators.
I do not have the default File Decorator set and got the following exception:

```
Warning: Exception caught by form: No file decorator found... unable to render file element Stack Trace:
```

The Answer to this is that one of your decrators must implement the empty interface Zend_Form_Decorator_Marker_File_Interface

Answer (score 0):

Also sometimes it happens to bug when using an ajax request. Try it without an ajax request and don't forget the multipart form.